# Using whole body balancer while executing timeline

Tags: nao-robot

I'm trying to use [whole body balancer](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/naoqi/motion/control-wholebody.html#case-2-balance-constraint) made by Aldebaran to make my nao dance more steadily and to be less dependent on the surface horizont level, to neglect some small tilt.

I've succeeded in requesting nao to [go to balance](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/naoqi/motion/control-wholebody-api.html#ALMotionProxy::wbGoToBalance__ssCR.floatCR), but enabling [balance constraint](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/naoqi/motion/control-wholebody-api.html#ALMotionProxy::wbEnableBalanceConstraint__bCR.ssCR) gives me nothing. For testing, I designed an ill-balanced timeline which leads robot to fall down when the body balancer is disabled and should keep the robot stable as log as it's enabled, that's what Aldebaran [declares](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/naoqi/motion/control-wholebody.html#when-use-it) as a use-case. However, the robot still falls down (I keep him vertical with my hand) and then goes to balance due to `ALMotionProxy::wbGoToBalance`. It is strange, however, that he reaches balance in a rapid move, rather than in `3.0` seconds that I requested.

My suggestion now is: whole body balancer needs some resources (joints) that are actually used by my timeline (it uses all the joints). Is it correct? Can anyone confirm or deny this?

The source I use is generally this one:

```
self.proxy = ALProxy("ALMotion")
self.proxy.wbEnable(True)
self.proxy.wbFootState("Fixed", "LLeg")
self.proxy.wbFootState("Free", "RLeg")
self.proxy.wbEnableBalanceConstraint(True, "LLeg")
```

I use this source inside a box in Choregraphe 1.14 and it is definitely called (it leaves logs I stripped out). And it definitely gives me no exceptions, I check and log them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that you must remove some joints from your timeline. 
The test is easy: disable for instance ankles from your timeline and see the results.

Disabling some joint is easy:

- open the timeline
- click the small pen beside the "Motion" caption on
  the left
- then uncheck some circles (for instance the LAnkleRoll
  circle): so those joint animation will be disabled.
- retest

Comment: That's sad. It renders the whole thing quite useless to me, since I expected it to correct my complex motion to adapt it to surface the robot stays on and to its tilt. And the motion uses the whole body. BTW, I discovered, that I can call `goToBalance` in a loop in parallel to the motion without disabling any resources and it works in general. So I guess Constraint should also work in the same manner. And actually I tried disabling some joints with no luck.